# jQuery Number formatter every 3s

Tags: jquery

The idea is to format number in a element every 3 seconds.
This works fine at the first executing, but from the second executing it turns the content in the  element to **NaN** :

```
<money>123456789</money>
```

And this is my script:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('money').each(function () {
        var item = $(this).text();
        var num = Number(item).toLocaleString('en');    
        $(this).text(num);
    });
}, 3000);
```

So is there a way to keep the content if it's already "123,456,789"?

Here's [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/iwolfcode/61yq87j2/6/)

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to try and convert it every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commas from the `.text()` before turning it into a number:

```js
// Mỗi 3 giây hiển thị kiểu tiền tệ
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('money').each(function () {
        var item = $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '');
        var num = Number(item).toLocaleString('en');    
        $(this).text(num);
    });
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<money>123456789</money>
```

Answer (score 0):

NAN is correct because `123,456,789` is not a number.
You need to save your original number in an attribute:

```html
<money data-number="123456789">123456789</money>
```

```js
var num = Number($('money').text()).toLocaleString('en');
$('money').text(num);

window.setInterval(function(){
    $('money').each(function () {

        var item = $(this).attr('data-number')*1 + 1;
        $(this).attr('data-number',item);
        var num = Number(item).toLocaleString('en');    
        $(this).text(num);
    });
}, 3000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ea83kuL/